# Как изменять размер (ширину и длину) txt файла при открытии

Tags: c#

**Для программы необходимо открывать текстовые файлы, при этом всегда одного размера по ширине и длине. Без влияния размера предыдущего закрытого файла**

Если открывать файл через Process.Start, то размер файла соответствует предыдущему закрытому файлу.

На гифке видно что при закрытии "большого" блокнота следующий файл будет такого же "большого" размера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде бы ерунда, но очень интересно узнать, можно ли задавать размер файла при запуске

Comment: У текстового файла нет ширины и длины. Ищите в настройках редактора, может есть опция не изменять размер окна.

Comment: Можно с помощью функций WinAPI задавать нужный размер. / Или же сделайте свой аналог Блокнота (кинуть на ВинФорму компонент TextBox) с желаемыми настройками.

Comment: Сделайте свою форму с текстбоксом и открывайте как диалог. Только учтите, мониторы разные бывают. Может размер шрифта 100% стоять, может 300%. То есть можете попасть в ситуацию, где текст просто не влезет в окно если размер будет фиксирован. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048509/12888024